# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined" when selected jqgrid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jqgrid, indexof

I have used jqgrid for a while.  I am getting an error when I select a row:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
> jquery.jqGrid.src.js:2465 $.jgrid.extend.setSelection
> jquery.jqGrid.src.js:2465 jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.7.1.js:658
> jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.7.1.js:271 $.jgrid.extend.setSelection
> jquery.jqGrid.src.js:2460 $.fn.jqGrid jquery.jqGrid.src.js:587
> $.fn.jqGrid.each.$.before.click.bind.ts.p.datatype
> jquery.jqGrid.src.js:2235 jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.1.js:3256
> jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

my grid definition is here:

```
var sql4 = 'select id_num, est_number, customer, product, rev, w, l, fw, fl, expr1009, status, comments from schema.table where customer = "' + customer + '" and est_number = "' + est_num + '"';
$("#the_table").jqGrid({
    url:'thescript.php?sql=' + sql4,
    height: 300,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    width: 650,
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:["ID","Estimate","Customer","Product","Rev","W","L","FW","FL","Expr1009","Status","Comments"],
    colModel:[
        {name:"id_num",index:"id_num",width:"10"},
        {name:"est_number",index:"est_number",width:"10"},
        {name:"customer",index:"customer",width:"10"},
        {name:"product",index:"product",width:"10"},
        {name:"rev",index:"rev",width:"10"},
        {name:"w",index:"w",width:"10"},
        {name:"l",index:"l",width:"10"},
        {name:"fw",index:"fw",width:"10"},
        {name:"fl",index:"fl",width:"10"},
        {name:"expr1009",index:"expr1009",width:"10"},
        {name:"status",index:"status",width:"10"},
        {name:"comments",index:"comments",width:"10"}
    ],
    rowNum:10000,
    sortname: 'id_num',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: '',
    ondblClickRow: function(id){
        //do some stuff here
    }
})
.jqGrid('filterToolbar')
.trigger('reloadGrid');
```

}

I cannot figure out what the problem is, as it seems the grid works fine otherwise.

I have noticed that in the following jqgrid function, the id = 1 for ever row (this info is contained in the variable ***pt***.

```
setSelection : function(selection,onsr) {
    return this.each(function(){
        var $t = this, stat,pt, ner, ia, tpsr;
        if(selection === undefined) { return; }
        onsr = onsr === false ? false : true;
        pt=$t.rows.namedItem(selection+"");
```

The next line is where the error occurs.  The variable ***pt*** has 4 nodes that all have id: 1.

```
if(!pt || pt.className.indexOf( 'ui-state-disabled' ) > -1 ) { return; }
```

** Amswer **

I added the `key:true` option the the `id_num` field in the `ColModel`.  Each row of the grid had the SAME ID, so it was causing a problem.  I think is error happens most often when you do not have unique IDs. in your grid.

Comment: It's important to know which version of `jqGrid` you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) in any way:

```js
url: 'thescript.php?sql=' + encodeURIComponent(sql4)
```

instead of

```js
url: 'thescript.php?sql=' + sql4
```

Probably you should send `sql` parameter not as the part of URL, but inside of POST data. In the case you should use

```js
url: 'thescript.php',
postData: {
    sql: function () {
        return 'select id_num, est_number, customer, product, rev, w, l, fw, fl,' +
            ' expr1009, status, comments from schema.table where customer = "' +
            customer + '" and est_number = "' + est_num + '"';
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**: The error will be in [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.base.js#L2464-2465) of code of `setSelection`. So `pt.className` is `undefined`. It's very strange, but you can validate that you have no `id` duplication in the grid.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: You don't answered on my question about the *version* of jqGrid which you use.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is jqgrid 4.1.1

Comment: I have used this version for a long time, and I have implemented 10 to 20 production grids that have worked well...  Just not sure why I am having this error.

Comment: I updated the question.  Please check it out, maybe it gives you an idea.  Thanks!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: I updated my answer parallel to you. I suppose that the reason are the *data* which you use as input.

Comment: yes that seems to be the problem i guess i would like to use the `id_num` field as the unique ID.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: You can just add `key: true` as additional property of the column "id_num". It's important to understand that the ids must be unique not only inside of grid, but on the *whole page*. In many cases you can use `idPrefix: "someText"` to solve the problem.

Comment: hmmm, thanks that is a great point, because i have about 7 or 8 grids on this one page.  Thanks, Oleg, you are awesome at jqgrid!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: By the way, introduction of `idPrefix` option was my suggestions some time ago, but I think it's implemented *after* version 4.1.1. In the first implementation was some small bugs which was important in case of usage `addRowData`. So I recommend you at least to try the latest jqGrid 4.3.3.